# Setting cell to rich text with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, grails, apache-poi

I have a Grails app that uses Apache POI, and I am trying to append rich text to a cell. As soon as I try to append text with a specific XSSFFont, I get an error.

```
- IndexOutOfBoundsException occurred
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString.setStylesTableReference(XSSFRichTextString.java:439)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:344)
```

this is the code I am using to append the rich text:

```
private def addStringToCell(XSSFCell cell, String text, XSSFFont font) {
    XSSFRichTextString richText = cell.getRichStringCellValue()
    if (font == null) {
        richText.append(text)
    } else {
        richText.append(text, font)   <- i only get the exception if this happens
    }
    cell.setCellValue(richText)   <- exception occurs here
}
```

Comment: Is this writing to a new workbook, or an existing one you're appending to? And what version of Apache POI are you using?

Comment: I am using an excel template to generate a new excel file. This use-case is when I have already added text to a cell, and I need to add additional colored text to that cell. Version of POI: 3.7

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to POI 3.10 beta 2 (the latest version), to see if it is a bug that has already been fixed?